# Class to retrieve external data

Tags: vba

I have recently come to use VBA class modules in my code.

Based in part on an answer on Stack Overflow, I bought *VBA Developer's Handbook* and *Professional Excel Development*, but it took me a long time to 'get' classes (though I still have a long way to go).

I wrote myself a `GetExternalData` class, as one of the very common tasks I undertake in Excel VBA is incorporating data from other sources into my reports.

My thought was that the class could take care of deciding the best way of getting the data, based on the source and how the data is to be used, so my `getExternalData` method was using a 'Variant' so that I could use the same variable whether I return a `Collection`, `Array`, `Dictionary` or `Worksheet`.

However, when I attempted to pass the Collection to another function which expects a collection I was getting an error. I noticed the locals window showed as 'Variant/Object/Collection', so I tried setting the value to an Object rather than a Variant which works.

My question on Stack Overflow was actually about this practice (`Dim as Object... set = Collection`).

TODO:

1. At the moment, I don't have anything coded for Access database connections
2. I check the first element of a collection, and assume all items are similar types and have the same number of elements (for arrays)
3. I know there's debate on the merits of Hungarian - at the moment, I find it useful (have been using it for a long time in Access (tbl, qry) and in VBA user-forms (txt, cmb), so implementing it into my VBA made sense - so I don't really want to get into that debate
4. There's also mixed opinion on accessors vs public variables. If I create a letter then I create a getter, except where I'm storing the return Cols in a collection

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum dataReturnType
   arrayVals
   collectionVals
   dictionaryVals
End Enum

Public Enum sourceFileType
   csv = 1 '
   xls = 10 'old Excel
   mdb 'old Access
   xlsx = 100 'new Excel
   xlsm 'new Excel macro-enabled
   accdb 'new Access
End Enum

Private Enum getDataMethod
   ADO_Record_Set
   Web_QT
End Enum

Private strFilePath As String
Private strFileName As String
Private enumFileType As sourceFileType
Private strConnString As String
Private strExtendedProperties As String
Private strSelectClause As String
Private strFromClause As String
Private colReturnFields As Collection
Private enumRetrievalMethod As getDataMethod
Private strFormatString As String
Private boolIMEX As Boolean
Private boolHDR As Boolean
Private intkeyCol As Integer
Private rngOutput as Range
Public WSname As String
Public WhereClause As String
Public RtnType As dataReturnType

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   boolHDR = True
   boolIMEX = True
   Set colReturnFields = New Collection
   strSelectClause = "*"
End Sub

Property Let FilePath(fullPathOnly As String)
   If Left(fullPathOnly, 4) = "http" Then
      enumRetrievalMethod = Web_QT
      If Right(fullPathOnly, 1) = "/" Then strFilePath = fullPathOnly Else strFilePath = fullPathOnly & "/"
   Else
      enumRetrievalMethod = ADO_Record_Set
      If Right(fullPathOnly, 1) = "\" Then strFilePath = fullPathOnly Else strFilePath = fullPathOnly & "\"
    End If
End Property

Property Get FilePath() As String
   FilePath = strFilePath
End Property

Property Let FileName(fName As String)
   strFileName = fName
   Select Case Right(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStr(strFileName, "."))
      Case Is = "txt", "csv", "lst"
         enumFileType = csv
      Case Is = "xls"
         enumFileType = xls
      Case Is = "xlsx", "xlsb"
         enumFileType = xlsx
      Case Is = "xlsm"
         enumFileType = xlsm
      Case Is = "mdb"
         enumFileType = mdb
      Case Is = "accdb"
         enumFileType = accdb
   End Select
End Property

Property Get FileName() As String
   FileName = strFileName
End Property

Property Let ReturnFields(colNums As Variant)
    Dim colNum As Variant
    Select Case VarType(colNums)
      Case Is < vbVariant
         colReturnFields.Add colNums
    Case Else
      For Each colNum In colNums
        colReturnFields.Add colNum
      Next
   End Select
End Property

Property Let externalDataKeyColumn(colNum As Integer)
   intkeyCol = colNum
End Property
Property Get externalDataKeyColumn() As Integer
   externalDataKeyColumn = intkeyCol
End Property

Public Function getExternalData() As Variant
   Dim ReturnVals As Object
   Dim DataProcessor As Object
   Set DataProcessor = New DataProcessor
   Select Case enumRetrievalMethod
      Case Is = getDataMethod.ADO_Record_Set
         Set ReturnVals = doConnectRS
         Select Case Me.RtnType
            Case Is = dataReturnType.arrayVals
            getExternalData = DataProcessor.collection2Array(ReturnVals, Me.externalDataKeyColumn, True)
            Case Is = collectionVals
               Set getExternalData = ReturnVals
            Case Is = dictionaryVals
               Set getExternalData = New scripting.Dictionary
               Set getExternalData = DataProcessor.collection2Dictionary(ReturnVals, Me.externalDataKeyColumn)
         End Select
      Case Is = getDataMethod.Web_QT
         Set ReturnVals = doConnectQT
         Select Case Me.RtnType
            Case Is = dataReturnType.arrayVals
               getExternalData = ReturnVals.UsedRange
            Case Is = collectionVals
               Set getExternalData = DataProcessor.array2Collection(ReturnVals.UsedRange, Me.externalDataKeyColumn)
            Case Is = dictionaryVals
               Set getExternalData = DataProcessor.array2Dictionary(ReturnVals.UsedRange, Me.externalDataKeyColumn)
         End Select
   End Select
End Function

Private Function doConnectRS() As Collection
   'RecordSet Constants
   Const adOpenStatic = 3
   Const adLockOptimistic = 3
   Const adCmdText = &H1
   Dim dp As New DataProcessor
   Dim objRecordSet As Object, objConnection As Object
   Dim varRS As Variant
   Dim connString As String, SqlStatement As String
   Dim colNum As Integer, rowNum As Integer
   Dim colRS As New Collection
   Dim keyCol As Variant
   If Not compatibleSource Then Exit Function
   connString = getConnectionProperties
   SqlStatement = "Select " & strSelectClause & " FROM " & strFromClause
   If WhereClause <> vbNullString Then SqlStatement = SqlStatement & " WHERE " & WhereClause
   Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   objConnection.Open connString
   objRecordSet.Open SqlStatement, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
      If colReturnFields.Item(1) = "all" Then
         colReturnFields.Remove (1)
         For colNum = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            colReturnFields.Add colNum
         Next
      End If
      Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
         ReDim varRS(1 To colReturnFields.Count)
         For colNum = 1 To colReturnFields.Count
            If IsNull(objRecordSet.Fields.Item(CLng(colReturnFields.Item(colNum) - 1))) Then
               varRS(colNum) = vbNullString 'If the SQL statement returns Null populate with vbNullString rather than Null
            Else
               varRS(colNum) = objRecordSet.Fields.Item(CLng(colReturnFields.Item(colNum) - 1))
            End If
         Next
         colRS.Add varRS
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
      Loop
      Set objRecordSet = Nothing
      Set objConnection = Nothing
   Set doConnectRS = colRS
End Function

Private Function compatibleSource() As Boolean
   Select Case enumFileType
      Case Is > xlsx
         If Application.Version < 12 Then
            MsgBox "Incompatible source file selected!", vbCritical
            compatibleSource = False
         Else
            compatibleSource = True
         End If
      Case Else
         compatibleSource = True
   End Select
End Function

Private Function getConnectionProperties()
Dim HDR As String
If boolHDR Then HDR = "HDR=YES" Else HDR = "HDR=NO"
Select Case enumFileType
   Case Is = xls
      strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & strFileName & ";"
      strExtendedProperties = "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"
      strFromClause = "[" & WSname & "$]"
   Case Is = csv
      strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"
      strExtendedProperties = "Extended Properties=""text; FMT=Delimited;"
      strFromClause = strFileName
   Case Is = xlsx
      strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & strFileName & ";"
      strExtendedProperties = "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;"
      strFromClause = "[" & WSname & "$]"
   Case Is = xlsm
      strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & strFileName & ";"
      strExtendedProperties = "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"
      strFromClause = "[" & WSname & "$]"
End Select
getConnectionProperties = strConnString & strExtendedProperties & HDR & ";"
If boolIMEX Then getConnectionProperties = getConnectionProperties & "IMEX=1;"
getConnectionProperties = getConnectionProperties & """"
End Function

Private Function doConnectQT() As Worksheet

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qT As QueryTable

If rngOutput Is Nothing Then
   Set ws = Worksheets.Add
   Set rngOutput = ws.Range("a1")
Else
   Set ws = rngOutput.Parent
End If

myFileName = "URL; " & Me.FilePath & Me.FileName

    Set qT = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=myFileName, Destination:=rngOutput)
      With qT
        .Name = "myQT"
        .fieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
         qT.Delete

Set doConnectQT = ws

End Function
```

For the sake of completeness, I will also post the 'DataProcessor' class which I use to convert the returned collection to a dictionary or array if needed

```
Public Function collection2Array(colIn As Collection, Optional ByVal keyCol As Integer, Optional writeOut As Boolean) As Variant
   Dim rowCount As Long, colCount As Long
   Dim arrOut As Variant

   Select Case VarType(colIn.Item(1))
     Case Is >= vbVariant 'if the collection contains arrays
         ReDim arrOut(1 To colIn.Count, 1 To UBound(colIn.Item(1))))
         For rowCount = 1 To UBound(colIn.Item(1))
            For colCount = 1 To UBound(arrOut, 2)
               arrOut(rowCount, colCount) = colIn.Item(rowCount)(colCount)
            Next
         Next
      Case Else
         If writeOut Then 'we'll return a 2D array with 1 column suitable for writing directly to a worksheet
            ReDim arrOut(1 To colIn.Count, 1 To 1)
            For rowCount = 1 To colIn.Count
               arrOut(rowCount, 1) = colIn.Item(rowCount)
            Next
         Else
            ReDim arrOut(1 To colIn.Count)
            For rowCount = 1 To colIn.Count
               arrOut(rowCount) = colIn.Item(rowCount)
            Next
         End If
   End Select
   collection2Array = arrOut
End Function

Public Function collection2Dictionary(colIn As Collection, Optional ByVal keyCol As Integer, Optional compareMode As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As scripting.Dictionary
   Dim colVal As Variant
   Set collection2Dictionary = New scripting.Dictionary
   collection2Dictionary.compareMode = compareMode
   If keyCol = 0 Then keyCol = 1
   For Each colVal In colIn
      collection2Dictionary.Item(colVal(keyCol)) = colVal
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: Just a note, the reason people dislike hungarian is because the prefixes are too generic. Knowing that someting is, say, an `Integer` is not worth the clutter. Knowing that something is an array index, though, or a combo box, that's more useful. I recommend the excellent Joel Spolsky post on the topic: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: One suggestion for you as an upgrade someday: implement each of the data types (csv, xls, accb, etc...) as its own class, but have them implement the same interface (you might call it IDataSource or some other suitable thing).  That way, the logics for each different source are loosely coupled from the others, making your code more robust and easier to update (if the xls code isn't working, you won't risk making an update that might break the others).  Also, you can make a "factory" method that returns an IDataSource that can tell by the file name which actual class to instantiate.

Comment: @Kaz - I've seen that article. The VBA developer's handbook recommends Hungarian, and I find it useful. For example, the Dictionary and Collection have the same methods, so context doesn't tell me which is which, but the prefix does. And I work for a transport company, where we have "Connote Numbers" and "Run Numbers" which can actually have alpha characters, so `strConnoteNumber` and `strRunNo` leave no ambiguity as to what data-type they actually are

Comment: @Blackhawk - That's actually a really good idea! Thank you very much, that had never occurred to me, and is exactly the type of feedback I was hoping for

Answer (score 3):

`GetExternalData` isn't ideal for a class name; if methods are *verbs*, classes/types are *nouns*. Class names should be nouns, not verbs.

When making a class, unless the class' primary concern is *presentation*, I leave `MsgBox` and other notifications out of it, and raise custom runtime errors instead.

---

This one caught my eye:

> ```
> Property Let FileName(fName As String)
>    strFileName = fName
>    Select Case Right(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStr(strFileName, "."))
>       Case Is = "txt", "csv", "lst"
>          enumFileType = csv
>       Case Is = "xls"
>          enumFileType = xls
>       Case Is = "xlsx", "xlsb"
>          enumFileType = xlsx
>       Case Is = "xlsm"
>          enumFileType = xlsm
>       Case Is = "mdb"
>          enumFileType = mdb
>       Case Is = "accdb"
>          enumFileType = accdb
>    End Select
> End Property
> ```

If the extension is unknown, you'll have inconsistent internal state in your object. If the file name contains dots (e.g. `some.file.with.dots.csv`), there's a bug in your `Case` expression that will leave `enumFileType` unassigned. Consider using the much more robust `FileSystemObject` to retrieve a file's extension, instead of implementing your own:

```
Private Function GetFileExtension(ByVal path As String)
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        GetFileExtension = .GetExtensionName(path)
    End With
End Function
```

Also, `Case Is =` is rather uncommon; this would be equivalent:

```
Property Let FileName(ByVal value As String)
    Dim extension As String
    extension = GetFileExtension(value)
    Select Case extension
        Case "txt", "csv", "lst"
            enumFileType = csv
        Case "xls"
            enumFileType = xls
        Case "xlsx", "xlsb"
            enumFileType = xlsx
        Case "xlsm"
            enumFileType = xlsm
        Case "mdb"
            enumFileType = mdb
        Case "accdb"
            enumFileType = accdb
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "File format '." & extension & "' is not supported."
    End Select
    strFileName = value
End Property
```

Notice the `Case Else` that *prevents* assigning `strFileName` with a value that we don't know what to do with, by raising a runtime error.

---

The casing isn't consistent; in VBA public members should be `PascalCase`. I'm not going to say a word about Hungarian notation, except "ugh" (that's not a word, is it?).

> *There's also mixed opinion on accessors vs public variables.*

Not really. A public field in a standard module is a global variable, and that's pretty much universally recognized as a bad practice whenever avoidable. A public field in a class module **breaks encapsulation**, which literally defeats the purpose of a class module. In every single object-oriented language, a public field is bad practice. How is VBA any different? Avoid public fields. Period.

What's up with the indentation in `doConnectQT`?

> ```
>     End With
>          qT.Delete
>
> Set doConnectQT = ws
>
> End Function
> ```

The indentation of `getConnectionProperties` isn't consistent with the rest of the module either. I've copied your code into a class module and [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) cleanly indented the whole thing in a split second.

Speaking of Rubberduck, here's what its *code inspections* have to say:

```
Warning: Constant 'adOpenStatic' is implicitly Variant - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 134
Warning: Constant 'adLockOptimistic' is implicitly Variant - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 135
Warning: Constant 'adCmdText' is implicitly Variant - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 136
Suggestion: Public field 'WSname' breaks encapsulation -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 37
Suggestion: Public field 'WhereClause' breaks encapsulation -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 38
Suggestion: Public field 'RtnType' breaks encapsulation - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 39
Warning: Member 'Worksheets' implicitly references ActiveWorkbook - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 221
Hint: Member 'FilePath' is implicitly public - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 48
Hint: Member 'FilePath' is implicitly public - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 58
Hint: Member 'FileName' is implicitly public - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 62
Hint: Member 'FileName' is implicitly public - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 80
Hint: Member 'ReturnFields' is implicitly public - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 84
Hint: Member 'externalDataKeyColumn' is implicitly public -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 96
Hint: Member 'externalDataKeyColumn' is implicitly public -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 99
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'strConnString' to a smaller scope. -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 26
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'strExtendedProperties' to a smaller scope. - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 27
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'rngOutput' to a smaller scope. -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 36
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'WSname' to a smaller scope. -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 37
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'WhereClause' to a smaller scope. -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 38
Suggestion: Move module-level variable 'RtnType' to a smaller scope. -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 39
Warning: Instruction contains multiple declarations - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 138
Warning: Instruction contains multiple declarations -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 140
Warning: Instruction contains multiple declarations - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 141
Suggestion: Consider renaming enum member 'csv' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 10
Suggestion: Consider renaming enum member 'xls' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 11
Suggestion: Consider renaming enum member 'mdb' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 12
Suggestion: Consider renaming enum member 'xlsx' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 13
Suggestion: Consider renaming enum member 'xlsm' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 14
Suggestion: Consider renaming variable 'dp' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 137
Suggestion: Consider renaming variable 'HDR' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 190
Suggestion: Consider renaming variable 'ws' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 217
Suggestion: Consider renaming variable 'qT' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 218
Warning: Return value of function 'getExternalData' is never used. - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 103
Hint: Parameter 'fullPathOnly' is implicitly passed by reference -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 48
Hint: Parameter 'fName' is implicitly passed by reference - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 62
Hint: Parameter 'colNums' is implicitly passed by reference - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 84
Hint: Parameter 'colNum' is implicitly passed by reference - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 96
Hint: Return type of member 'getConnectionProperties' is implicitly 'Variant' - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 189
Suggestion: Parameter 'fullPathOnly' can be passed by value -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 48
Suggestion: Parameter 'fName' can be passed by value - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 62
Suggestion: Parameter 'colNums' can be passed by value - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 84
Suggestion: Parameter 'colNum' can be passed by value -  CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 96
Warning: function 'getExternalData' is not used - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 103
Hint: Object reference 'dp' is self-assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 137
Hint: Object reference 'colRS' is self-assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 142
Warning: Variable 'strFormatString' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 32
Warning: Variable 'WSname' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 37
Warning: Variable 'WhereClause' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 38
Warning: Variable 'RtnType' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 39
Warning: Variable 'rowNum' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 141
Warning: Variable 'keyCol' is never assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 143
Warning: variable 'strFormatString' is not used - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 32
Warning: variable 'dp' is not used - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 137
Warning: variable 'rowNum' is not used - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 141
Warning: variable 'keyCol' is not used - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 143
Suggestion: Property 'ReturnFields' has no getter - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 84
```

Now, some of these inspection results are popping up only because I have no client code to consume the class, call its members and assign its public fields, but ignoring that, you can see that there are a number of serious issues with this code - variables declared but never used, `ReturnFields` property being write-only (consider making it a method instead), members are *implicitly* `Public`, parameters are *implicitly* passed `ByRef` when they could very well be passed `ByVal`, some variables have cryptic 2-3 letter names, etc.

---

I'm not sure I like how you're passing arbitrary concatenated SQL to an ADODB connection - the WHERE clause should already be part of the query, and parameters should be `?` question marks, and your code would be taking in actual *parameter values* (say, using a `ParamArray` parameter, or an array of values) and creating ADODB `Parameter` objects and executing an ADODB `Command` instead of concatenating arbitrary SQL.

`</SqlSecurityRant>`

I think replacing `Null` values with `vbNullString` should be some setting that the client code can decide about: "no value" is semantically very different from "empty value".

I'm not sure why you're late-binding ADODB here. You lose IntelliSense, take a performance hit at runtime, and you wouldn't need to redefine the adEnum constants.

---

In `getConnectionProperties` you're using the function's return value as if it were a local variable:

```
getConnectionProperties = strConnString & strExtendedProperties & HDR & ";"
If boolIMEX Then getConnectionProperties = getConnectionProperties & "IMEX=1;"
getConnectionProperties = getConnectionProperties & """"
```

Avoid this, it hurts readability and *looks* like a recursive call. And declare the function `As String` - right now it's implicitly returning a `Variant` - there's so much `Variant` and `Object` in this code, you have implicit type conversions through the roof!

---

I'd like to point out this inspection result:

> Hint: Object reference 'colRS' is self-assigned - CR14196VBA.ExternalData, line 142

Consider this code:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As New Collection
    foo.Add "test1"
    Set foo = Nothing
    foo.Add "test2" ' runtime error? isn't foo supposed to be Nothing?
End Sub
```

When using `As New` at procedure scope like you do here:

> ```
> Dim colRS As New Collection
> ```

...you're changing how VBA treats that object's lifetime, in a way that can introduce subtle and surprising bugs. Avoid `As New` at procedure scope.

---

It's hard to tell module-scope variables from globals. Adepts of Hungarian notation usually annotate their private fields with some `m_` prefix for that purpose. I have a better way (granted, that `T` prefix is totally Hungarian - as is the `I` prefix I use on all my interface classes... Hungarian *does* have a number of benefits... just not in variable naming):

```
Private Type TClassName
    Foo As String
    Bar As Integer
    '...
End Type

Private this As TClassName

Public Property Get Foo() As String
    Foo = this.Foo
End Property

Public Property Let Foo(ByVal value As String)
    this.Foo = value
End Property

Public Property Get Bar() As Integer
    Bar = this.Bar
End Property

Public Property Let Bar(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Bar = value
End Property

'...
```

By wrapping *all* your private fields in a `Private Type`, you make it idiot-proof what the class' fields are, and you have one single field (`this`) to refer to *everywhere in the class* - that way whenever you read the code and see anything prefixed with `this.`, you *know* you can only be looking at a private field.

It also eliminates the casing/naming problem: the properties and their corresponding underlying private field names can match without breaking any naming convention, and without having to resort to funky `m_` prefixes.

As for the relevance of Hungarian notation (sorry!), when your IDE *tells you* what the type of a variable is, what purpose does the prefix serve?

[image: colReturnFields (variable: Collection]

Meaningful names and consistent naming conventions are much more useful than Hungarian notation: I know I'm looking at a *collection*, or *group of things*, simply because `Fields` is plural - the `col` prefix isn't really useful at all.

[image: enumRetrievalMethod (variable: getDataMethod]

If I wasn't paying attention, I'd think `getDataMethod` is a `Function` or some member/procedure; the enum type name should simply not start with a verb - it's a type, therefore it's a *noun*.

I guess that's a wrap :)

(also: avoid underscores in identifier names - spare your future self headaches, stick to `PascalCase` for types and their members, and `camelCase` for locals and parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're entirely right about having a CASE ELSE for unknown filetypes, and I'm pleased to learn about Scripting.FileSystemObject for retrieving file extensions, much better than finding the period in the name! As for your code inspections, I'm not sure what to make of most of that. Could you provide me with some info on your `this` technique? I don't immediately see the benefit. As for Hungarian, "when your IDE tells you what the type of a variable is [in break mode]", it can be useful to know at design-time, too! "strConnoteNumber" leaves no doubt that it's alphanumeric

Comment: "I know I'm looking at a collection, or group of things, simply because Fields is plural - the col prefix isn't really useful at all" - it's useful to me to know whether the data-type is a Dictionary, or a Collection, or an Array (since collections and dictionaries have the same methods, context doesn't help). And you're right about the MsgBox - that's a hold-over from some testing, and should have already been removed!

Comment: Try Ctrl+i on any variable at design time... these RD screenshots are at design time, too. As for the inspections, they identify unused variables, parameters passed `ByRef` that can/should be `ByVal`, members that are *implicitly* `Public` that could use an explicit access modifier, things declared without an explicit type that are implicitly `Variant`, etc. The benefits of the `this` field are already in the answer - you'll never clash with a global variable if you do that, and it's easier to tell a field from a local or parameter too. Not to mention instant serialization if you need it.

Comment: I reread your answer a few times, and I get the private type `this.` technique now - very clever! when it comes to `ByRef`/`ByVal`, I assumed it would be more efficient not to create a copy of the variable if it's not needed?

Comment: If you're into *nano-optimization*, perhaps. VBA/VB6 is the only language I know of that passes parameters by reference by default - VB.NET, Java, C# - all pass parameters by value by default; I doubt `ByVal` would ever be a bottleneck - and in VBA a `ByRef` parameter can be rewritten by the procedure, intentionally or not - IMO it's best to keep `ByRef` for things that *require* to be passed by reference, and that odd time you *do* need to modify its value and pass that back to the caller. It's all about *communicating intent* =)

Comment: I know this is not a forum, but this is a great opportunity for me to actually learn. It was this article on Stack Overflow that convinced me accessors are unnecessary if all you're doing is storing and returning in a 'dumb container': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters. I don't see that `Ctrl+i` is more convenient than `col`*. Finally, my intention is to move everything to late binding, as my organisation has Excel from XP to 2010 still in use (which is why I do the version validation in the class)

Comment: Odd, that SO page is presenting overwhelming evidence and explanation about why public fields are a bad idea and why exposing class data as properties is better. If that won't convince you, I don't know what will. Your class is not a "dumb data holder" (that's exactly what a `Public Type` is; a structure exposing a bunch of public fields and nothing more), it embeds functionality and presents an interface - arguably a number of these fields should simply not be exposed at all.